# Cannot Specify Document Id When Creating Document in Firestore

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, php-7.1

I am trying to create a node in Google Firebase, and use its unique id to create a Document in Google Firestore of the same name.

I'm using Google's PHP Firestore Client: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php-firestore

And I've read through their documentation: http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/v0.5.1/firestore/writebatch

Here is my code:

```
<?php

use \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
use \Google\Cloud\Core\Timestamp;
use \Google\Cloud\Firestore\Transaction as FirestoreTransaction;
use \grptx\Firebase as FirebaseClient;

class FirestoreTest
{
    public function create()
    {
        $client = new FirebaseClient();
        $database = $client->getDatabase();

        $org = array(
            "acl" => array(),
            "people" => array()
        );

        $ref = $database->getReference("/clients/")->push($org);
        $key = $ref->getKey();

        $config = array(
            "projectId" => "xxx",
            "keyFile" => json_decode(file_get_contents("/xxx/firebase_auth.json"), true)
        );

        $firestore = new FirestoreClient($config);
        $batch = $firestore->batch();
        $batch->create("/clients/".$key, [
            'organization_ID' => $key
        ]);

        print_r($key); // this key gets generated, no errors occur.
    }
}
```

This is the version of PHP I am using:

```
php -v
PHP 7.1.10-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Sep 29 2017 17:33:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.10-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 
1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need a write batch for a single write:

```
$docRef = $firestore->collection('clients')->document($key);
$docRef->set(['organization_ID' => $key]);
```

Also, check out the docs. We added PHP samples:

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data